# How to handle values with spaces in Process.Start in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a button, and I use Process.Start when clicking it, although I select data from textBox1.Text.

Although this data on textBox1.Text does not come out properly if there are spaces in textBox1.Text

e.g. textBox1.Text = testing_123 works

although textBox1.Text = testing 1 2 3   doesn't work (it will only include "testing")

The code is below:

```
    private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("test.exe", textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply quote the args like this before passing:

```
private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("test.exe", "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes around your argument string.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the spaces:

```
TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ",string.Empty)
```

Or if you want to substitute another character (underscore) then try:

```
TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ","_")
```

If you want to include the space then @Teoman has your answer...

It depends on what you mean by "*handle*".